# Determine whether it is a partial order set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

the question is:
"$A = \{4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$
For each of the following sets R< determine whether they are partial orders between
A and A (justify your answer!). When not, determine the least combined number of
additions/removals of elements to/from R< such that the result, denoted by PO<, is
a partial order."
There's quite a few parts, I think what I have done so far is correct, but I'm quite unsure about this question:
$R_< = \{(4, 4),(5, 5),(6, 6),(7, 7),(8, 8)\}$
I understand that reflexivity and antisymmetry hold, and transitivity doesn't, but I don't what pairs would I need to add to R< to make it hold transitivity besides just $(4, 5), (5, 6) (6, 7), (7, 8)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $A = \{4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$
>
> $R_< = \{(4, 4),(5, 5),(6, 6),(7, 7),(8, 8)\}$

The relation $R_<$ is reflexive, symmetric, *and transitive* over $A$.

Transitivity means: $\forall (x,y,z){\in} A^3: [(x,y){\in}R_<\wedge (y,z){\in} R_<\to (x,z){\in}R_<~]$

Or equivalently: $\neg\exists (x,y,z){\in} A^3: [(x,y){\in}R_<\wedge (y,z){\in} R_<\wedge (x,z){\notin}R_<~]$

And this holds, since every pairs of the form $(x,y),(y,z)$ that are in $R_<$ will always find that the corresponding pair $(x,z)$ must be in $R_<$.   There is no way to form a counter example.

Comment: So it is transitive because it can't be proven that it's not? I'm a bit confused, sorry.

Comment: Exactly.  A universal claim can be proven by a demonstration that a counter example cannot exist.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

The set $R = \{ (4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,7), (8,8) \} $ **is** transitive.
Suppose that $(a,b) , (b,c) \in R$. In every ordered pair the first and second elements are equal. Thus $a = b$ and $b = c$. But then $a = c$ and $(a,a) = (c,c) \in R$.